# Hashing a hash in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I am new to python a need a little help with the program I have written below. I want to start with a text string which converts into a hash which currently works.

But the problem I am having is hashing that hash and then increment them automatically up to the final hash which is `b2 = 0c9ae7b6896fc93039ab966aba9b65a7` in a while loop until it stops at that final hash: `0c9ae7b6896fc93039ab966aba9b65a7`.

Any suggestions on what I could do for this would be appreciated. Here is my code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import hashlib

mystring = input('Hash it: ')                                                                             

b = hashlib.md5(mystring.encode())            
b2 = "0c9ae7b6896fc93039ab966aba9b65a7"
print(b.hexdigest())

while ( b!= b2 ):
   print ((b.hexdigest()))
else:
   print ("done")
```

Comment: Your code does not run, the indentation is off.

Comment: Hi bastelflp - Sorry I included the code that did not run. The above code runs in Python 3, but it just prints the entered string in md5. I am trying to get it to run in a while loop until it reached the intended value "b2"

Comment: You are comparing a hash to a string. And you are not changing anything in the while loop, so this never comes to an end.

Comment: So how could I hash the output hash in coding terms?

Comment: What do you want to do? Hash your hash again? How do you want to get to the final hash b2?

Comment: hash the hash all the way until b2 is reached, all along the way printing each hash value.. I cannot get my head around how the while loop will work for that.

Answer (score 3):

This works for the while loop, but is not converging, as there is no rule how to reach the hash b2 (according to the comments added to the question):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import hashlib

mystring = input('Hash it: ')

b1 = hashlib.md5(mystring.encode()).hexdigest()
b2 = "0c9ae7b6896fc93039ab966aba9b65a7"
print(b1)

while b1 != b2:
    b1 = hashlib.md5(b1.encode()).hexdigest()  # calculate next hash
    print(b1)

print("done")
```

You have to actually adapt the value you compare in the while loop. Read more on while loops here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Comment: Wow, thanks Bastelflp, hashing the hash was really screwing me up but looking at your code it makes much more sense now. I thank you for your help :)

Comment: Great if it helps. If this answers your question you can upvote it or "mark it as resolved".